# Add a class to existing bundle of classes

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I need to add a new class to current properties.

Currently we have

```
.class1 .class2{
width:150px;
}
.class1 .class50{
more properties
}
.class1 .class10 .class8 .class5 .class50{
more properties
}
```

So the above lets say shows a div on all pages, but I would like to make a change on 1 page only to have a width of  250px. I am not sure how I can accommodate that, I have tried to add .newclass to the string of classes so wherever class 1 was showing I was adding .newclass to that line (didn't work)

I also tried to add ,.newclass before or after for example:

```
.class1 .class10 .class8 .class5 .class50, .newclass{
more properties
} (didnt work either)
```

any suggestions?

Here's a sample HTML

```
<div id="class33" class="class34 class35" style="display:none;"> 
    <div class="class7"> 
        <ul class="class33 class1"> 
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i hope for your sanity's sake that you aren't actually naming classes `class1 class2 classN`

Comment: What is the HTML structure on the page?

Comment: no I am not lol, that's just examples. the page is fairly simple:

<div id="class33" class="class34 class35" style="display:none;">
    <div class="class7">

        <ul class="class33 class1">        
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

Comment: *One* `class` attribute per element, containing a white-space delimited list of class-names.

Comment: Hi Derik,  I ended up finding every class that has .class1 that is being used for that 1 page and copy/paste it in the same css file, and then I just changed the name on the new pasted classes from .class1 to .newclass, is that a bad approach? it works, but yea now we have some items 2 times... but I can't find a better way for this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you also use the , between every .class ? 
.class1, .class2, .clas..

You could also think about creating a new class or if it's possible to use a class of a higher rank?

Comment: well I didn't because right now it's working fine, so i figured the structure is good, I am just making changes to it. I could of course copy the entire page into a new css and then do a find a replace on class1 to newclass and then only include the new css on the 1 page, but this can not be the right solution, there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you know what that css means.

```
.class1 .class10 .class8 .class5 .class50, .newclass{
  more properties
}
```

This means that `more properties` applies to an element with `.class50` that's inside `.class5` which is inside `.class10` inside `.class1` AND any element with class `.newclass`.  If you're trying to override anywhere `.class1` is, you'd need to duplicate all child cascades below `.class1` too.  Like below:

```
.class1 .class10 .class8 .class5 .class50,
.newclass .class10 .class8 .class5 .class50 {
  more properties
}
```

Ultimately, this would be a nightmare just to handle one page of outliers.  (Not to mention, if this happened for one page, it will undoubtedly happen in more later)

If the element occurs only once on the page, you might try adding an id to it, which has a higher specificity ranking (and thus would override class styles).

**Another thought: jQuery?**
If you're already using JS/jQuery on the site, you might just handle it there.

```
$('.class1').each(function () {
  $(this).width(250);
});
```

Comment: oh that is a great idea.. I didn't try to add an ID, let me try this and I'll let you know

Comment: didnt work either, I even tried to hardcode width:250px!important on the page, but that didnt work either.

Comment: hi so I ended up finding every class that has .class1 that is being used for that 1 page and copy/paste it in the same css file, and then I just changed the name on the new pasted classes from .class1 to .newclass, is that a bad approach? it works, but just want to know what you think.

Comment: It's not the best approach, but one-offs are often unpretty.  If you're really just changing one one class's width, then I would just say `.newclass { width: 200px !important; }`, add that `.newclass` to your `.class1` div and that should override your `.class1` width.  It gets ugly if other styles have to change as a result of the new width.

Answer (score 0):

You should just make a new class and apply it on that one page.

```
.newclass
{
  width: 250px;
}
```

In your markup, `newclass` will need to be specified **second** so it will override `class1`.

```
<div class="class1 newclass">
</div>
```

You could also use a per-specific override with the `<style>` tag for the `class1` class and not have to add `newclass` at all. But some will say this violates the separation of structure and style, so maybe only use it if changing the original markup (to add the `newclass` class) is not possible.

```
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
  .class1
  {
    width: 250px;
  }
  </style>
</head>
```

Comment: yup! tried that too, for some reasons when i do that it's ignoring all the styles for that section, as if there is no css code to the classes... weird weird weird.

Comment: I am not a big fan to add css elements outside the .css files sorry I am an application developer I have to be anal with my code :)

Comment: I'm with you on the code separation. Just an extra option, no problem! :)

Comment: well I might have to just do that, or copy all the css and paste it back it on the same css files and then on the duplicated part change the class1 to newclass, it would suck cause all the other code is the same

Answer (score 0):

You need separate classes **use ",":**

```
.class1, .class2{
width:150px;
}
.class1, .class50{
more properties
}
.class1, .class10, .class8, .class5, .class50{
more properties
}
```